# ¿Como puedo hacer que el value de un select se desactive?

Tags: javascript, html5

Hola me gustaría saber como puedo hacer que se desactive el value de un select de manera que cuando este selecciona una de las opciones del `select` la otra opción se desactive y de manera viceversa desde el javascript.

```html
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Tipo registro *</label>
    <select class="form-control" id="tipo_registro_L" name="tipo_registro_L">
        <option value="0">SELECCIONE UN TIPO</option>
        <option value="nino">NIÑO</option>
        <option value="adulto">ADULTO</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes deshabilitar una opción agregando el atributo `disabled` como a continuación:

```html
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Tipo registro *</label>
    <select class="form-control" id="tipo_registro_L" name="tipo_registro_L">
        <option value="0">SELECCIONE UN TIPO</option>
        <option value="nino" disabled>NIÑO</option>
        <option value="adulto">ADULTO</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Para realizar la deshabilitación con JavaScript tienes que marcar el atributo como verdadero, como a continuación:

```js
var option = document.querySelector('#tipo_registro_L option[value="adulto"]');

option.disabled = true;
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Tipo registro *</label>
    <select class="form-control" id="tipo_registro_L" name="tipo_registro_L">
        <option value="0">SELECCIONE UN TIPO</option>
        <option value="nino">NIÑO</option>
        <option value="adulto">ADULTO</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Otra opción es ocultarlo marcando la propiedad de estilo `display` con el valor `none`, como a continuación:

```js
var option = document.querySelector('#tipo_registro_L option[value="adulto"]');

option.style.display = "none";
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Tipo registro *</label>
    <select class="form-control" id="tipo_registro_L" name="tipo_registro_L">
        <option value="0">SELECCIONE UN TIPO</option>
        <option value="nino">NIÑO</option>
        <option value="adulto">ADULTO</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Si lo que quieres es que después de seleccionar una opción todas las demás se desactiven puedes usar esto:

```js
function desactivarOpcionesNoSeleccionadas() {
  var select = document.getElementById("tipo_registro_L");
  var selectOptions = select.getElementsByTagName("option");

  if (select.selectedIndex) {
      for (var i = 0; i < select.length; i++) {
          if (selectOptions[i] != selectOptions[select.selectedIndex]) {
              selectOptions[i].disabled = true;
          }
      }
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group" >
  <label>Tipo registro *</label>
  <select class="form-control" id="tipo_registro_L" name="tipo_registro_L" onchange='desactivarOpcionesNoSeleccionadas()'>
      <option value="0" selected>SELECCIONE UN TIPO</option>
      <option value="nino">NIÑO</option>
      <option value="adulto">ADULTO</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

#### Explicación:

El atributo `onchange="desactivarOpcionesNoSeleccionadas()"` hará que cuando el usuario seleccione una opción, llamara la función `desactivarOpcionesNoSeleecionadas()"`.

En esa función, declaramos unas variables que apuntan hacia el elemento `<select>` con `id="tipo_registro_L"`
y otra que apunta hacia una lista de todos los `<option>` dentro del `<select>` del que hablamos anteriormente.

`if (select.selectedIndex) { //... }` verificara que efectivamente haya una opción seleccionada.

Dentro del `if(){}` iteramos por todas las opciones dentro del `<select>` y verificamos si el `<option>` actual es diferente al `<option>` seleccionado. Si es asi, modificamos su atributo `disabled` y lo igualamos a `true`. Si es el atributo `<option>` es el seleccionado, no hacemos nada, dejandolo activo.